# How to import Navit into Eclipse and use it in own android project

Tags: android, eclipse, import, navigation

I'd like to create a custom application which would use 3D navigation. I found the Navit opensource project, which has all functionalities that I need. I checked out the last Navit source code from the repository found [here](https://navit.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/navit/trunk/navit/). After downloading the project I wanted to import it into eclipse workspace as described [here](http://wiki.navit-project.org/index.php/Eclipse). But there I ran into a problem, because when I navigate to Android folder, there is no project found, so the import can't be done. I tried importing as "new android project from existing code" as described in the manual. I even tried by manual creation of the project, but with no success. What am I missing?

Thank you for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

- Start a new project, pick import SVN 
  svn co svn://svn.repository.with.navi.code.you.want.to.import
- Select C/C++ project
- Choose now GNU Autotools(if there is nothing under toolchains install autotools(autoconf,automake/gettext) via your os packagemanager)
- Open a terminal, switch to your workspace navit folder and invoke `cmake ./`
  you now have makefile that matches your local setup
- In Eclipse, pick "build all" and you should get a binary
- Run as application and you your local build should start