# Navit Android Project In Eclipse

Tags: android, c, eclipse, navit

I checked out this before I ask my question: [How to import Navit into Eclipse and use it in own android project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15502293/how-to-import-navit-into-eclipse-and-use-it-in-own-android-project)
However, it does not work as it is answered.
Could anyone please explain how to use Navit in an Android project?
Most of them are C files.
http://download.navit-project.org/navit/src/navit-0.2.0.tar.gz
Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

Hey Yousef can you elaborate the issues you are facing ? 
Navit has now moved to Github, and you can see the android build script here : https://github.com/navit-gps/navit/blob/trunk/ci/build_android.sh

There is automated builds where you can also get a lot of informations about how the automated builds are done. Here's one for example : circleci.com/gh/navit-gps/navit/545 you can scroll down to the build_android.sh block to get the detailed output.

There's also automated builds available in the beta channel : https://play.google.com/apps/testing/org.navitproject.navit ( updated almost daily )